# Android EditText: How to process data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have created an application which is a simple form. Users will enter username data and password into each editText pair provided.

My problem comes with extracting this data. Normally, I would extract by the "@id/" value assigned to each editText, but as I am using an adapter and a separate xml file for the row this is not possible, as each editText has *the same id*.

Does anyone have an idea how I might go about doing this?

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/cancelbutton" />
```

list.xml : used for individual row

```
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/g" >
    </ImageView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="email"        
        >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
        android:text="password"  
        >
    </EditText>
```

```
public class ColorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public SocialSiteAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

// GetView does what exactly..?
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);


    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);


    if (s.equals("Blue")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
    } else if (s.equals("Green")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.g);
    } else if (s.equals("Red")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.r);
    } else if (s.equals("Yellow")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.y);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: sure, I have added to code for the two xml files, and the adapter code. The code inside main activity is simply list.setAdapter()

Answer (score 1):

You need to first select the row and then inside the row select the `EditText`s by their known `@id`

To list the entries you could go like:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
   Layout row = (Layout) listView.getItemAtPosition(i); /// XXX
   EditText t = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.firstLine); 
   // ...
}
```

You need to check by yourself in the line with XXX what the getItem.. call returns and change accordingly.

Comment: Hi, how can I go about selecting each row individually?

Comment: Thanks Heiko. I should mention that I the main activity is implementing a ListView and not an Activity, so I cannot actually use the getListView method.

Comment: In that case when the activity is the ListView, you should be able to directly call `getCount` and `getItemAtPosition`?